# React Native AsyncStorage Access on App Load

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await, asyncstorage

I need to access data from AsycStorage to pass to one of my functions, WidgetGenerator, immediately when the app is opened. However, there doesn't seem to be a way to call `getData()` and wait for it to set the value of `initVals`, it just continues executing code sequentially in `WidgetGenerator()` and passes `undefined` to the component it returns because `getData()` hasn't returned yet. Also, it doesn't seem like react likes it when I make WidgetGenerator an async function. What do I do so that I will be able to access AsyncData on loading?

```
const getData = async () => {
        try {
            const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@1629349495937')
            if (jsonValue != null) {
                //console.log(JSON.parse(jsonValue));
                initVals = JSON.parse(jsonValue);
            }
        } catch(e) {
            // error reading value
        }
    }
```

```
    function WidgetGenerator(props) {
        
        switch (props.args[0]) {
            case "heading":
                return <UIComponents.UIHeading
                            text={props.args[1]}
                            id={props.id}
                            init={initVals ? initVals[props.id] : undefined}
                        />;
            case "checkbox":
                return <UIComponents.UICheckbox
                            text={props.args[1]}
                            id={props.id}
                            callback={props.callback}
                            init={initVals ? initVals[props.id] : undefined}
                        />;
        }
        
        return <View />;
    }
    
    return (
        <View>
            {widgetArray.map((data, index) => <WidgetGenerator key={index} id={index} args={data} callback={collectData}/>)}
            <UIComponents.UISubmitButton callback={submitData} />
        </View>
        
    );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some code pieces missing to give a full picture what's going on exactly, but I think I got it anyways. So you have to resolution strategies available:

1. Use a sync storage solution, that can get you the data directly
2. Get the data asynchronously, display a loading indicator or similar while loading

#### Use a sync storage solution

If you are able to install native dependencies you can install a library for sync data access like [react-native-mmkv](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-mmkv). Just go through its documentation, should be straightforward.

#### Load the data asynchronously

There are many ways to do it. Ideally, you load your app data once on the app start while showing a splash screen, and store the data in a global store (can be something as simple as a JS object), so you can access them directly during runtime.
However, a general pattern for async data loading in react looks like this:

```
function Component() {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

  // load the data
  useEffect(() => {
    const asyncAction = async () => {
      try {
        const _data = await getData();
        setIsError(false);
        setData(data);
      } catch (e) {
        setIsError(true);
      }
    }
  }, []);

  if (isError) {
    return // view indicating an error
  }

  if (data == null) {
   return // view indicating loading
  }

  return <View>{/* actual implementation that is using data*/}</View>
}
```

There are many tutorials about this topic, that you can google.